# Query regarding analysis of regression output

Tags: r, regression, interpretation, outliers

I have made 2 models from based on some social media data.First one is with outliers and the 2nd one is without outliers.

```
> summary(lm.with_outliers)     ## with outliers

Call:
lm(formula = Lifetime.Post.Total.Impressions ~ ., data = posts)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-113420  -18903   -8995    1668 1039786 

Coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)       1.634e+05  6.311e+04   2.589  0.00997 ** 
Page.total.likes -9.758e-01  6.817e-01  -1.431  0.15311    
Category         -1.133e+04  4.406e+03  -2.571  0.01048 *  
Post.Month        1.430e+02  3.449e+03   0.041  0.96695    
Post.Weekday      1.746e+02  1.785e+03   0.098  0.92215    
Post.Hour        -7.046e+02  8.579e+02  -0.821  0.41194    
Paid              2.616e+03  8.164e+03   0.320  0.74885    
comment           7.068e+02  3.801e+02   1.859  0.06369 .  
like              1.285e+02  2.642e+01   4.864 1.64e-06 ***
share            -6.884e+02  2.459e+02  -2.800  0.00535 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 74550 on 411 degrees of freedom
  (5 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.1789,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1609 
F-statistic: 9.951 on 9 and 411 DF,  p-value: 7.437e-14
```

---

```
summary(lm.without_ouliers)

Call:
lm(formula = Lifetime.Post.Total.Impressions ~ ., data = posts_rm_out)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-62173 -12336  -6056   4175 220899 

Coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)       1.065e+04  2.532e+04   0.421  0.67428    
Page.total.likes  2.824e-01  2.721e-01   1.038  0.29993    
Category         -1.077e+04  1.783e+03  -6.038 3.55e-09 ***
Post.Month       -2.189e+03  1.366e+03  -1.603  0.10969    
Post.Weekday     -7.569e+02  7.056e+02  -1.073  0.28406    
Post.Hour        -1.375e+02  3.389e+02  -0.406  0.68507    
Paid              8.777e+03  3.239e+03   2.710  0.00703 ** 
comment          -8.732e+01  2.231e+02  -0.391  0.69571    
like              8.359e+01  1.101e+01   7.590 2.24e-13 ***
share             5.481e+00  1.187e+02   0.046  0.96320    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 29280 on 403 degrees of freedom
  (5 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.326, Adjusted R-squared:  0.311 
F-statistic: 21.66 on 9 and 403 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Now, I am trying to analyze the differences between two.I have confusion over below qs-

1. I see in the 2nd model each unit increase in like can increase target by 128 units , where in the model without outliers  each unit increase in like increases  target by approx. 84 units. But p-value for like (2.24e-13 ) is lesser in 2nd model, still can we say 'like' has more impact in 1st model?

2.R square and F statistics are better in 2nd model,so I guess this establishes better acceptance of 2nd model.what this ultimate 'p-value: < 2.2e-16' is signifying?

Answer (score 0):

1) I would formulate it like that: the effect is stronger in the first model but rejecting the null hypothesis is less likely (but still quite strongly supported)

2) No! It just says that your outlier(s) increases more the residual variance than it increases the trend. It is not a criteria to select for one or the other model

Here I would try to first understand why the models with and without outliers produce different results and discuss it (what are the effect of my outliers on my conclusions).

Choosing between the two options should be (if possible) more driven by a careful examination of the outliers (are values realistic, why are they so far away, ...).